# How to show and hide the button on click listview item?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have one listview and in the listview i m using one progressbar, and i want when i'll click on the progressbar then there must show three buttons below the progressbar, and when i'll again click on the progressbar then these these three button must be hide.??
please help me.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this?

container is the where has your 3 buttons

progressbar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    container.setVisible(View.GONE);

 }
});
```